# Asp .Net Core DirectoryNotFound Exception

Tags: exception, iis, asp.net-core

I need help, I was trying to publish my application to production in windows server and i it gave me this error

> An error occurred while starting the application.

I runt dotnet command on windows server to check what was the error and this appeared on command line

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NoPaper_new\wwwroot\files\    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String
>   root, ExclusionFilters filters)    at
>   NoPaper.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in
>   C:\Users\A0H79224\source\repos\NoPaper\NoPaper\S tartup.cs:line 53
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
>   NoPaper.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\A0H79224\source\repos\NoPaper\NoPaper\Program.cs:line 11

basically I have a folder in wwwroot called files which has 3 subfolders where it is possible to upload files to but they are empty.

So i checked the folder in IIS and on wwwroot the files folder doesn't exist.

Why was it not published? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: goto those files properties and make sure that "Copy to Output Directory" is not "Do not copy"

Comment: problem is there was no files on the folder

Comment: Glad for help :)

Comment: what files did you add in wwwroot ?